# COM component works 100% from a console app, but fails when called from a service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-services

I need your advice for the following C# code:

```
EgarDDSEnt.IIVDDSEnt dds = null; // This line executes fine.
dds = new IVDDSEnt();  // This line fails with an exception ...
dds.Connect("username", "password"); // ... which makes this line fail too.
```

Here are the symptoms:

Windows Server 2008 R1:

- Code fails when executed from a Windows service app.
- Code works 100% when executed from a console app.

Windows 7:

- Code works 100% when executed from a Windows service app.
- Code works 100% when executed from a console app.

The class IVDDSEnt() is a COM object that is installed you install the "ivolatility SDK".

**Update:**

- When I execute "System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()" from the console application, it returns "D:\MyDevDirectory\"
- When I execute "System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()" from the service application, it returns "C:\windows\system32\".
- The application is actually the *same binary* for both service and console (its a hybrid app that can run in console mode, or install itself as a service if you pass "-service" to it on the command line).

**Update:**

Added try/catch, and "e.GetBaseException" (defined as "Returns the exception which is the root cause of one or more subsequent exceptions"):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving
the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{FA944FE7-AEB8-4B5B-8315-11D19B1F6264} failed due to the following error:
80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
at PhiDataOnSchedule.ConsoleApplication.MyMain(Boolean dummyRun)
```

**Update:**

Still can't fix the problem - the easiest way might be to just upgrade from Windows Server 2008 R1 to Windows Server 2008 R2 (if it works on Win7, and Windows Server 2008 R2 has a Win7 core, perhaps it'll work around the underlying issue somehow?).

Comment: "fails with an exception" you think it would be useful to tell us **what** exception?

Comment: Definitely need the exception dump or we're not going to get anywhere.

Comment: The exception didn't seem to be very helpful: 'MyHelper.LogThis.OnException: Exception "NullReferenceException": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."'. Is there any way I can get a more comprehensive exception dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I have to specify an account to run the service under?

For a complete example of how to code this up, see:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/LtoE.aspx?artkw=LINQ%20to%20WCF#ShowIt

Search for the text: "When the installer is run, it will allow you to enter the service login credentials to run under, using the following dialog box":

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That's probably a rights problem. Check under which service account the service runs and its rights. Then either change the service account or expand its rights.

Comment: Tried this, no luck. I tried ticking "Allow service to interact with desktop". I tried setting the service login to be "Administrator / Mypassword". I tried turning UAC off. I also tried "oleview" to set the permissions for the COM objects to be run by the "Administrator". Any other ideas?

Comment: @Gravitas: if the COM Server is out-of-process you may have to configure it be accessible. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690141(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE` is "Server execution failed".

This would indicate the component should be out of process, but the COM runtime could not start the executable (or, maybe, load the dll into a host process).

Looking for activity against the file containing the component with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) might give you a clue (it could be permissions: Process Monitor could confirm this).

Comment: Cheers, I'll try this in the morning. Its one of those annoying problems: it works 100% as a service on my development machine, in the office, but breaks when its deployed to the remote Amazon EC2 server.